# Change language in android application resources

Tags: android

after studying about supporting multiple languages in android application, i have good the basic idea about how i can make resources for different languages within application, for example i want to add Spanish language in my application so in res direction within my application i have added values-en directory and in that direct i have added strings resource and within that resource i have added strings with values of Spanish text, in my application default language is English now i want to know how can i switch it to Spanish, i have the resources ready i just need to change my application language to Spanish

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: `i want to add Spanish language in my application so in res direction within my application i have added values-en directory` **WRONG**: you should have added `values-es`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in your `onCreate()` after `setContentView`:

```
String languageToLoad = "es";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

You also have to change your value folder to **values-es**. values-en is for English. Hope this helps.

To change App locale follow below code:

1) **Create** *LocaleUtils* class:

```
public class LocaleUtils {

    private static Locale sLocale;

    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        sLocale = locale;
        if(sLocale != null) {
            Locale.setDefault(sLocale);
        }
    }

    public static void updateConfig(ContextThemeWrapper wrapper) {
        if(sLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setLocale(sLocale);
            wrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);
        }
    }

    public static void updateConfig(Application app, Configuration configuration) {
        if (sLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            //Wrapping the configuration to avoid Activity endless loop
            Configuration config = new Configuration(configuration);
            // We must use the now-deprecated config.locale and res.updateConfiguration here,
            // because the replacements aren't available till API level 24 and 17 respectively.
            config.locale = sLocale;
            Resources res = app.getBaseContext().getResources();
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
}
```

2) In *Application Class*:

```
public class YourAppName extends Application {
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        LocaleUtils.setLocale(new Locale("es"));
        LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this, getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this, newConfig);
    }
}
```

3) **Remember**, Your Application class name and `<application android:name=".YourAppName">` should be same. Otherwise it won't work. Kudos to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922319/7235049) answer.

Comment: it will change application language or current activity ? and should i do this in MainActivity or in Application Activity ?

Comment: It will change the language of current activity. Do you want to change language of whole app at a time? Then you have to configure the Application class.

Comment: this code executes well in MainAcitivty but when i execute it in Application class i get this error 

" Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"